# least square optimization NOT CURVE FITTING

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

i'm dealing with a least squares(SCIPY) problem. usually a least sq problem has the X data and Y data given and the general form of the function is given such as linear/quadratic/log and based on the x and y data, we optimize the parameters of the curve equation-this is CURVE FITTING

but what i wanna do is given the Y data and the exact form of the function, estimate what the X data would be...the x-data is multidimensional, i.e there are 40 parameters of which only 4 are realized in every experiment. I've shown an example below-

```
X data       Y data      function
a,b,c,d       0.4        a+b+c+d
a,c,d,e       0.2        a+c+d+e
c,d,e,k       0.7        c+d+e+k
..................................
..................................
..................................


so:
a+b+c+d = 0.4
a+c+d+e = 0.2
c+d+e+k = 0.7
...........
............
..........
```

ASSUME WE HAVE LARGE AMOUNTS OF SUCH DATA

so the function is exactly known, it is simply  the sum of the x data. there are many parameters to be estimated,(40), in each experiment only 4 of these parameters are realized, and each x data has the corresponding y value
IS THIS EVEN POSSIBLE??

*NOT IMPORTANT* I AM WORKING ON A QUESTION RELATED TO DNA-TRANSCRIPTION FACTOR BINDING

Comment: [How to Transcribe DNA Using Python 3 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUlOizd0Hh0), try search `python DNA-TRANSCRIPTION scipy.optimize` - thanks for interesting topic

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get up to 40 linearly independent sets of those equations, and then use methods of systems of linear equations to solve for the coefficients.